# HTML5 Find nearby geolocation

Tags: android, html, cordova, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am creating an application and I need the app to find the nearest car rentals from the user location or if they input in a postcode. Currently i have looked into previous posts on stack overflow and found the below which finds the users current location. I am new to this so apologies in advance but I am not sure on how I would go from here to make the data display.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 Geolocation</title>
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script>
            // Integration with google maps
            function loadMap(lat, lng) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

                var settings = {
                    zoom: 14,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), settings);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng, 
                    map: map, 
                    title: 'Your Position!'
                });  

                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Position Found!';
            }

            // Initialize geolocation
            function initialize() {             
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Checking...';

                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                        onSuccess, 
                        onError, {
                            enableHighAccuracy: true,
                            timeout: 20000,
                            maximumAge: 120000
                        });
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Geolocation not supported.';
                }
            }

            // Map position retrieved successfully
            function onSuccess(position) {
                var data = '';

                data += 'latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '<br/>';
                data += 'longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '<br/>';
                data += 'altitude: ' + position.coords.altitude + '<br/>';
                data += 'accuracy: ' + position.coords.accuracy + '<br/>';
                data += 'altitudeAccuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy + '<br/>';
                data += 'heading: ' + position.coords.heading + '<br/>';
                data += 'speed: ' + position.coords.speed + '<br/>';

                document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = data;

                loadMap(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            }

            // Error handler
            function onError(err) {
                var message;

                switch (err.code) {
                    case 0:
                        message = 'Unknown error: ' + err.message;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        message = 'You denied permission to retrieve a position.';
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        message = 'The browser was unable to determine a position: ' + error.message;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        message = 'The browser timed out before retrieving the position.';
                        break;
                }

                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = message;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="status"></div>
        <div id="data"></div>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 640px; height: 480px"></div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

How would i get the app to display a list of nearest car rentals when the user selects current location or inputs their postcode?

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you getting your list of car rental places from?

Comment: That is what i don't understand. I am new to this and done a lot of research but can't figure out how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to be building a database of car rental locations, MongoDB has built-in geolocation / geospatial query capabilities. In a general sense, it sounds like you need to buy or rent a list of the agencies, get that into a database format, then query that database with geo queries in your html.